# Indexing Column for LIKE styled query on very Large data set

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I have an Postgres table with around 70 millions row.I've never worked with such a large amount of data before.

My data are Stock option where the composit key is something like this :
AAPL.US where AAPL ( apple ) the symbol of the Stock and US the region where it's traded.

When trying to do a custom query using the composit key such as

`SELECT * FROM stock_prices WHERE composit LIKE '%.US'`

It is extremely slow actually often simply crashing because it's too long. minimum of 10-15 minutes at very best.

I'm trying to find a way to index the process since it looks like it could be fastened.

There is only around 70 or so different " regions " for a total of 70 millions row.

I've tried indexing the " composit key " this way but that didn't do much

`CREATE INDEX idx_composit ON stock_prices(composit);`

Any query on the dataset is very very slow to say the least so my purpose in doing this is to be able to 'organize' my data in a better way for subsequent queries so that any simple query doesn't take ~15 minutes+++ / crash.

Comment: Try the following page: PostgreSQL LIKE query performance variations

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566717/postgresql-like-query-performance-variations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try making it SARGable by using function-based index:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON stock_prices(REVERSE(composit));

SELECT * FROM stock_prices WHERE REVERSE(composit) LIKE REVERSE('%.US');
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=6a866995dcffa590ce2216797542d97d)**